# Multiple mutable borrows with Graph-like data structures

Tags: rust, directed-acyclic-graphs

I am trying to write a program that will find the longest path in the graph (i.e. the greatest depth) for a directed graph which is always a rooted or multi-rooted tree.

The specs of the assignment require I use DFS and memoization, but multiple mutable references occur when performing the DFS. Is there any other way to do this?

I thought about using `HashMap`s instead of internal `Graph` fields, but it would just produce the same error on mutability of the `HashMap`. I've found several other questions on the Rust user forum and here, but none of them gives the advise on how to resolve this. Am I supposed to use "unsafe" code or some other strategy?

```
use std::io;

struct Node {
    neighbours: Vec<usize>,
    depth: usize,
    visited: bool,
}

impl Node {
    fn new() -> Node { Node { neighbours: Vec::new(), depth: 0, visited: false } }
    fn add_neighbour(&mut self, node: usize) { self.neighbours.push(node); }
    fn neighbourhood_size(&self) -> usize { self.neighbours.len() }
}

struct Graph {
    nodes: Vec<Node>,
    depth: usize,
}

impl Graph {
    fn new() -> Graph { Graph { nodes: Vec::new(), depth: 0} }
    fn nodes_number(&self) -> usize { self.nodes.len()}
    fn add_node(&mut self) { self.nodes.push(Node::new()); }
    fn node(&mut self, i: usize) -> &mut Node { &mut self.nodes[i] }

    fn dfs(graph: &mut Graph, index: usize) {
        if !graph.node(index).visited {
            graph.node(index).visited = true;
        }
        match graph.node(index).neighbourhood_size() == 0 {
            true => { graph.node(index).depth = 1; },
            false => {
                for &i in graph.node(index).neighbours.iter() {
                    // multiple mutable references 
                    Graph::dfs(graph, i);
                }
                graph.node(index).depth = 
                    1 + graph.node(index).
                    neighbours.iter().
                    map(|&x| graph.node(x).depth).
                    max().unwrap();
            }
        }
        if graph.node(index).depth > graph.depth {
            graph.depth = graph.node(index).depth;
        }
    }
}


fn main() {
    let mut input_line = String::new();
    io::stdin().read_line(&mut input_line);
    let n = input_line.trim().parse::<usize>().unwrap();
    // to avoid counting from 0 or excessive use of (-1)
    let mut graph = Graph::new(); graph.add_node();
    for _ in 0 .. n {
        let mut input_line = String::new();
        io::stdin().read_line(&mut input_line);
        let separated = input_line.
            split(" ").
            collect::<Vec<_>>();
        let u = separated[0].trim().parse::<usize>().unwrap();
        let v = separated[1].trim().parse::<usize>().unwrap();
        if graph.nodes_number() <= u { graph.add_node(); }
        if graph.nodes_number() <= v { graph.add_node(); }
        graph.node(u).add_neighbour(v);
    }
    let n = graph.nodes_number();
    for i in 1 .. n {
        if !graph.node(i).visited { Graph::dfs(&mut graph, i); }
    }
    println!("{}", graph.depth);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are modifying your `graph` structure while iterating through a vector contained within it. The compiler has no way of verifying that you do not add or remove from the vector during the iteration, which would invalidate the iterator. This is the intuitive reason for the error.

The easiest way to avoid this is to take a copy of the vector before iterating over it, so the compiler can see that the iterator does not change. This is a little suboptimal but resolves the error for now. Another lifetime error is solved in a similar way (but without much cost) by copying the depth into a variable before doing a comparison.

```
use std::io;
use std::env;

struct Node {
    neighbours: Vec<usize>,
    depth: usize,
    visited: bool,
}

impl Node {
    fn new() -> Node {
        Node {
            neighbours: Vec::new(),
            depth: 0,
            visited: false,
        }
    }
    fn add_neighbour(&mut self, node: usize) {
        self.neighbours.push(node);
    }
    fn neighbourhood_size(&self) -> usize {
        self.neighbours.len()
    }
}

struct Graph {
    nodes: Vec<Node>,
    depth: usize,
}

impl Graph {
    fn new() -> Graph {
        Graph {
            nodes: Vec::new(),
            depth: 0,
        }
    }
    fn nodes_number(&self) -> usize {
        self.nodes.len()
    }
    fn add_node(&mut self) {
        self.nodes.push(Node::new());
    }
    fn node(&mut self, i: usize) -> &mut Node {
        &mut self.nodes[i]
    }

    fn dfs(graph: &mut Graph, index: usize) {
        if !graph.node(index).visited {
            graph.node(index).visited = true;
        }
        match graph.node(index).neighbourhood_size() == 0 {
            true => {
                graph.node(index).depth = 1;
            }
            false => {
                let neighbours = graph.node(index).neighbours.clone();
                for &i in neighbours.iter() {
                    // multiple mutable references
                    Graph::dfs(graph, i);
                }
                graph.node(index).depth = 1
                    + neighbours
                        .iter()
                        .map(|&x| graph.node(x).depth)
                        .max()
                        .unwrap();
            }
        }
        let depth = graph.node(index).depth;
        if depth > graph.depth {
            graph.depth = graph.node(index).depth;
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    env::set_var("RUST_BACKTRACE", "1");
    let mut input_line = String::new();
    io::stdin().read_line(&mut input_line);
    let n = input_line.trim().parse::<usize>().unwrap();
    // to avoid counting from 0 or excessive use of (-1)
    let mut graph = Graph::new();
    graph.add_node();
    for _ in 0..n {
        let mut input_line = String::new();
        io::stdin().read_line(&mut input_line);
        let separated = input_line.split(" ").collect::<Vec<_>>();
        let u = separated[0].trim().parse::<usize>().unwrap();
        let v = separated[1].trim().parse::<usize>().unwrap();
        if graph.nodes_number() <= u {
            graph.add_node();
        }
        if graph.nodes_number() <= v {
            graph.add_node();
        }
        graph.node(u).add_neighbour(v);
    }
    let n = graph.nodes_number();
    for i in 1..n {
        if !graph.node(i).visited {
            Graph::dfs(&mut graph, i);
        }
    }
    println!("{}", graph.depth);
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=6b2069db255193d41c359cc2f4076ea2&version=stable)

If you were to modify your approach so that you did not mutate the structure during the search (i.e. you stored the visited data elsewhere), the code would work without this copy. This would also be more friendly to concurrent use.

Comment: Thank you. What do you mean by "stored visited data elsewhere"? Having the depth data and the visited data in a vector? Wouldn't I then just have the same issue with those vectors? I am missing something

Answer (score 1):

Instead of taking a copy of the vector before iterating over it, you could also iterate over the indices:

```
for ni in 0..graph.node(index).neighbours.len() {
    let neighbour = graph.node(index).neighbours[ni];
    Graph::dfs(graph, neighbour);
}
```

The `neighbours` vector gets still borrowed for performing the iteration, but not for the whole course of the iteration:

1. `graph.node(index).neighbours.len()`: once at the beginning of the iteration for getting the length
2. `let neighbour = graph.node(index).neighbours[ni];`: in each iteration step for getting the neighbour at the current index

Like the copy approach, this solution is based on the constraint that the `neighbours` vector you are iterating over will not be changed by the call to `dfs`.

You can solve the remaining issues regarding multiple references in your code by providing immutable access to the graph nodes:

```
fn node_mut(&mut self, i: usize) -> &mut Node {
    &mut self.nodes[i]
}
fn node(&self, i: usize) -> &Node {
    &self.nodes[i]
}
```

Only make use of the mutable access via `node_mut` where necessary. For example when adding a neighbour: `graph.node_mut(u).add_neighbour(v);`